# base:split() implementation - faster options within R/data.table

Tags: r, algorithm, data.table

I want to perform association rule mining in R using `arules:apriori` function and that needs a `transactions` type input. This is nothing but list of factors with each element representing the unique set of products purchased in that transaction. An example below:

```
  products   transaction
1 {a,b}      1            
2 {a,b,c}    2            
3 {b}        3
```

In the package documentation, they recommend using `split` to generate this like so:

```
split(DT[,"products",with=FALSE], DT[,"transaction",with=FALSE])
```

But when I try the same on a large set of transactions, it is painfully slow. Example MWE below:

```
library(data.table)

#Number of transactions
ntrxn = 1000000

#Generating a dummy transactions table
#Recycling transaction vector over products
DT = data.table(transaction = seq(1,ntrxn,1) 
                ,products = rep(letters[1:3],ntrxn))[order(transaction)]

TEST = split(DT[,"products",with=FALSE], DT[,"transaction",with=FALSE])
```

Is there a way to speed this up by leveraging `data.table` `by` condition? I have tried this:

```
DT[,list(as.factor(.SD$products)),by=transaction]
```

But it just gives me back the `data.table` (which makes sense in hindsight). Is there a way a list of vectors using a similar expression but by leveraging the performant `data.table` internals to take care of the heavy lifting.

If `data.table` alone is not the answer here, I am really curious which approach would get me to the output I am looking for.

Comment: Compare `system.time(lst <- split(DT$products, DT$transaction))` and `system.time(lst <- split(DT[,"products", with=F], DT[,"transaction", with=F]))`see what you get from it. Almost two orders of magnitude difference. Don't quite know why that is happening, but I guess the previous one is what you should go by.

Comment: @Psidom - also compare `system.time(split(DT[,products], DT[,transaction]))` - the issue is the `with=FALSE`

Comment: There is a world of difference between the two! I did not even wait for the latter one to finish. Question for you - what is the difference between syntax 1 and 2?

Comment: @thelatemail From http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf, *DT[,j,with=FALSE] where j is a single integer returns a one column data.table, unlike DF[,j] which returns a vector by default*, so the `with` syntax returns a data.table which could have caused some overhead when passed to the `split` function.

Comment: Quite a bit faster on my computer: `system.time(DT[, .(.(products)), by=transaction])` It's the OP's last line of code wrapped in another `list()` to make a list column. Note `.()` is an alias for `list()`.

Comment: @Frank - that should be an answer, it's a definite improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the OP's last line of code to make a list column:

```
DT[, .(.(products)), by=transaction]
```

`.()` is an alias for `list()`. This is faster on my computer, anyways.